# Why updating arangoDB result in nginx error?

Tags: nginx, upgrade, arangodb

I have version 3.3.5 and want to upgrade to 3.3.11. The following script was used:

```
#Step 1 Copy the whole data directory of arango to another location, basically a backup

cp -R /var/lib/arangodb3 /folder

#Step 2 Stop the current running process

service arangodb3 stop

#Step 3 Installing new ArangoDB, adding the key and stuff (the below is for 16.04 Ubuntu)

curl -OL https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb33/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

sudo apt-get update
read -p "Enter the version zou want to upgrade to (For example 3.3.5)" version
sudo apt-get install arangodb3=$version

#Step 4 Start the process again with auto-upgrade option on
service arangodb3 start --database.auto-upgrade
```

At the end of step 3. when install the arango version this error pop up

```
Setting up nginx-core (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Do 2018-11-22 11:07:07 CET; 8ms ago
  Process: 16614 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16610 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1328 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 22 11:07:05 SB28 nginx[16614]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 22 11:07:06 SB28 nginx[16614]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 22 11:07:06 SB28 nginx[16614]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 22 11:07:06 SB28 nginx[16614]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 22 11:07:06 SB28 nginx[16614]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 22 11:07:07 SB28 nginx[16614]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Nov 22 11:07:07 SB28 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 22 11:07:07 SB28 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 22 11:07:07 SB28 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 22 11:07:07 SB28 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up arangodb3 (3.3.11) ...
Database files are up-to-date.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

An nginx error.My question is what is the role of nginx here in the upgrading of arango? (It seemed that arango cannot start it own nginx)

Comment: How are ArangoDB and Nginx related on your system? Did someone set up a reverse proxy for Foxx services running in ArangoDB, which might not work after the upgrade anymore (wild guess)?

Comment: So this is not the expected behavior of arango update and nginx is not part of inner arangodb, right?

Comment: ArangoDB does not use anything from Nginx. You can have a look at the third-party libraries here: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/tree/devel/3rdParty The integrated HTTP server is custom written. It uses `Boost.Asio`, but certainly no components from Nginx. The problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with nginx. Your arangodb installation did not finish correctly as it seems. As a consequence `systemctl deamon-reload` errored ... Please run

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure arangodb3`

and update your question with the output, please.